# Datatables fngetdata associative format

Tags: datatables

i have a question regarding datatables fngetdata. Im using `aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos);` to fetch a row from my datatable. I'm getting the data in array format. so my 1st column data will be `aData[0]`, 2nd will be `aData[1]` and so on. Can I get the data in associative array format. For example, 1st column name is `Group`, so can the data be `aData[Group]`? I need this format because, my datatable is being populated from a mysql table and whenever I expand the table to add columns, I have to change the positions of all other columns. I want to remove the positional dependency. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this using `mDataProp` option in `aoColumns`.